# as3: meaningful object identification while debugging

Tags: actionscript-3

I wanted to ask if there is a possibility to identify objects in more meaningful way during the debug. e.g. now in flex builder debug panel I see for example:

Object(@12131241241)

And ideally I wanted to have Object(@"field1:field2")... is there a way to do it. I believe in java it can be achieved by overriding toString method of the given class.... Tried same in as3 but it did not work

Comment: Did you try to override the toString and it did not work?

Comment: I tried and it did not. Maybe I've did it incompletely? This is how I did it  public override function toString():String
  {
   return this.xIndex + ":" + this.yIndex;
  }

Comment: Try casting it to string. I have used toString successfully in trace commands before.

Comment: Tracing will of course work with overrided `toString()` method, even without casting. But question is about debugger, as I understood. And, to be honest, I don't know any way to get more readable ids in Flash Builder debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Not answering your question directly here but there are many community debuggers around that give you more meaningful data. The IDE's Intellij Idea or Flash Develop and there are a few other projects such as http://demonsterdebugger.com/ or http://code.google.com/p/flash-console/ which give you an insane toolset for debugging.