# While debugging java app what information is shown for a variable in a stack frame

Tags: java

When I debug java app in Intellij Idea I see all variables in a stack frame like this:

```
object={java.lang.Object@77}
```

What does the number after "@" mean? It is different from what hashCode returns. hashCode returns number 2a134eca in hex representation which equals to 705908426 in integer representation. Numbers 77 and 705908426 are distinct.

Comment: Opps.. I meant to do this here... Looks like the allocation count number when the object was created. Create a bunch of objects and you can see that they are sequentially incremented. It might be per thread or per debug run, not sure. I could not find any documents on this... yet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The @ is the object count number since the app started. So @1012 means the 1012th object created since the app started.

**It is not the identity hashcode.**

Here is some proof: (I say this because I don't actually know, but I observed it)

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws Throwable {

    Object object = new Object();
    Object object1 = new Object();
    Integer foo = new Integer(5);
    Object object2 = new Object();
    String str = new String("bar");

    System.out.println("code :" + System.identityHashCode(object));

    RuntimeException exception = new RuntimeException();
    exception.printStackTrace(); //put breakpoint here


}
```

Output:
    code :789451787
    code :java.lang.Object@2f0e140b

789451787=2f0e140b By the way...

Output from IntelliJ Debugger:

```
static = org.boon.core.MyClass
args = {java.lang.String[0]@**97**}
object = {java.lang.Object@**98**}
object1 = {java.lang.Object@**99**}
foo = {java.lang.Integer@**100**}"5"
object2 = {java.lang.Object@**101**}
str = {java.lang.String@**102**}"bar"
exception = {java.lang.RuntimeException@**103**}"java.lang.RuntimeException"
```

I know this empirically, but I don't know the actual implementation, but I think it is related to issues like this:

[as3: meaningful object identification while debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538227/as3-meaningful-object-identification-while-debugging).

Answer (score 5):

> What does the number after "@" mean?

`@` is just a separator

Debuggers use the `toString` method of an object to display its value. And here is description of default implementation of `toString` method from the [**javadocs**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html):

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of
>   the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign
>   character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash
>   code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal
>   to the value of:

```
 getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

Comment: Sorry, but I still do not understand. By default hashCode supposed to return integer representation of memory address where this object is located. But while debugging my app in Intellij Idea a variable in a stack frame is shown like this object=java.lang.Object@72 while toString method returns java.lang.Object@2a134eca which is classname and hashCode separated by @. numbers 72 and 2a134eca are distinct. So what does 72 mean here?

Comment: Looks like the allocation count number when the object was created. Create a bunch of objects and you can see that they are sequentially incremented. It might be per thread or per debug run, not sure. I could not find any documents on this... yet.

Answer (score -3):

Class of **Object** followed by its memory address.

```
In {java.lang.Object@77ddeeff}:
Class name: java.lang.Object
Memory Address: 77ddeeff
```

So this convention name@address is just like our email addresses like in (abc@gmail.com) abc is located @ gmail.com

Comment: I am sorry, but both the proprietary Sun's JVM and OpenJDK typically do not use memory addresses when assigning hashcodes.

Comment: I wrote a program and IntelliJ is not using the identity hash code. java.lang.Object@2f0e140b != java.lang.Object@98

Comment: @eirirlar, its not a made up answer.  Object.toString() does return string of internal address (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()). The reason this answer is bad for here is, at the time I thought intellij console prints toString(), which was/is never the case.

Comment: Ok sorry for that